# Output not showing entirely in Python

Tags: python

The output when running a simple code breaks and is not entirely shown. What are the options to avoid the breaks?

```
22     December 23, 1989, Saturday, Late Edition - Final
23       December 22, 1989, Friday, Late Edition - Final
24     December 21, 1989, Thursday, Late Edition - Final
25     December 21, 1989, Thursday, Late Edition - Final
26     December 20, 1989, Wednesday, Late Edition - F...
27     December 20, 1989, Wednesday, Late Edition - F...
28      December 19, 1989, Tuesday, Late Edition - Final
29       December 18, 1989, Monday, Late Edition - Final
                             ...                        
605                             January 12, 2016 Tuesday
606                January 12, 2016 Tuesday 10:58 PM EST
607                 January 12, 2016 Tuesday 8:28 PM EST
608                 January 12, 2016 Tuesday 9:43 AM EST
```

Thanks!

PD: this is the code used to produce the file:

```
import json
import nltk
import re
import pandas

appended_data = []

for i in range(1989,2017):
    df0 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('NYT_%d.json' % i)])
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('USAT_%d.json' % i)])
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('WP_%d.json' % i)])
    appended_data.append(df0)
    appended_data.append(df1)
    appended_data.append(df2)


appended_data = pandas.concat(appended_data)

print(appended_data.date)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: You are probably using `pandas`. Pandas clips the output to make it more readable. You can force the series to display completely by converting it to a list first or (better) by writing it to a file and opening the file in a good spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the display width for pandas. The option you are looking for is `pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)`, but you may also find some other pandas options helpful which I use regularily:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
```

Detailed description can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html).